# How can function reference itself within itself in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory, stack, heap-memory

I understand recursion in terms of how code is executed and why you might need it. What I am wondering about is that is it possible that function can reference itself within itself?

Given the following example:

```
function factorial(num) {
  if(num ===0) {
    return 1
  }
  return (num * factorial(num - 1));
}

factorial(2)
```

I want to understand what is happening under the hood in terms of how variables are stored in memory and how they're called and why is it possible to reference `factorial` inside a `factorial` function.

The way I understand how it is going to be executed at the moment:

1. Declare a function `factorial` on the stack that will reference an object on the heap. At this moment `factorial` still points to nowhere
2. Create an object on the heap(function) that will calculate factorial
3. Call `factorial(2)` which will take the reference on the stack where `factorial` points to, find the function on the heap and call it.

What I don't understand is that how when `factorial` is called, will it know what is `factorial` and where to find it? Is it related to closures somehow?

Another example(jest)

```
  const someFunction = jest.fn((value) => {
    expect(someFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```

Why I can reference `someFunction` inside the `someFunction`, as mentioned I suspect it is related to memory and how variables are stored, but I don't grasp the concept fully.,

Answer (score 0):

By using a named function declaration/[expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_expressions), the call checks the inner scope of the function and if it is not inside, it check the name of the called function and then the outer scope.

> However, a name can be provided with a function expression. Providing a name allows the function to refer to itself, and also makes it easier to identify the function in a debugger's stack traces

By using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), the name of function is not set and does not remain by renaming as opposite of a named function declaration, where the name is always callable from the inner scope.

Answer (score 0):

The [Function Guide of the MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#scope_and_the_function_stack) contains the information you seek. There are multiple ways you can reference a function from inside its body. It boils down to the fact, that

> a function can access all variables and functions defined inside the scope in which it is defined

You can read this as a function can access everything defined in the scope in which it was defined. This includes itself.